# Оформление selecta после запроса Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, select

Всем привет. У меня такая вот проблема: уже 2 день никак не могу справиться.

Имеется страница, на которой расположен `select`, при выборе определенного значения в нем появляется другой `select` с подкатегориями. Все это работает, но есть одно большое НО...

Для оформления `Select` используется плагин `jqtransform`. Первый селект он, конечно же, оформляет, а вот второй, который формируется `Ajax`-сом, становиться обычным.

[image]

Код ajax

```
function showMapContact(str,lang){

$(function() {
    //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
    $("span.select_map").jqTransform();
});


$(function() {
    //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
    $("span.slmap").jqTransform();
});
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","show_map.php?mapq="+str+"&lang="+lang,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

Show_map.php

```
    <?php
$mapq = $_GET["mapq"];
$lang = $_GET["lang"];
include_once("class/Connect.php");
Connect::db_connect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM module_googlemaps_loc WHERE cat_id = '$mapq'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


?>
<span class="slmap">
    <select name='select2'>
        <option  value="" style="display: none;">qalaqebi</option>
<?php
while($location_array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $loc_id = $location_array['id'];
    $loc = $location_array["loc_$lang"];
    print "<option value='". $loc_id . "'>$loc</option>";
}
?>
    </select>
</span>
```

Страница на которую выводится.

```
<span class="select_map" style="position: relative;">
    <select name="select2" id="<?=$lang?>"  onchange="showMapContact(this.value, this.id)">
        <option  value="" style="display: none;">towns</option>
        <?php
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM module_googlemaps_category";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
        while($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
            $id2 = $r2['id'];
            $name2 = $r2["name_$lang"];
            ?>
            <option value="<?=$id2?>"><?=$name2?></option>
            <?php
        }

?>
    </select>


</span>
<br />

<span id="txt2"></span>
```

---

Перепробовал многое, так и не смог добиться результата.
Выручайте, пожалуйста)

Comment: А не пробовали новый селект сразу после появления тоже обрабатывать jqtransform'ом?

Comment: Так он обрабатывается,только не отображает как задуманно.Тупо загружается страница и весь JS,а потом видимо добавляется новый селект без оформления.

Comment: Именно. На момент отрабатывания скрипта он не знает о новом селекте и обрабатывает форму без него. Поэтому новый селект надо обрабатывать в частном порядке.

Comment: Да,но как?Даже если я его обработую в файле Show_map.php,он всеравно выводится обычным select-том.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убираем блок

```
$(function() {
    //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
    $("span.slmap").jqTransform();
});
```

и добавляем обработку селекта в ответ аякса

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    $("span.slmap").jqTransform();
}
```

Так же можно вместо

```
$(function() {
    //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
    $("span.select_map").jqTransform();
});
```

просто писать

```
$("span.select_map").jqTransform();
```

Comment: Thack you very much.)
И вправду работат.Если что ему везде обязательно добавлять проверку на xmlhttp.readyState?

Comment: xmlhttp.readyState проверка смотрит, вернулся ли ответ от сервера и если успешно вернулся происходят дальнейшие манипуляции с полученными данными.

Comment: Выходит,что jquery совершенно не знал о существовании оформления,без подтверждения.Понятно,спасибо еще раз,выручили.

Answer (score 3):

Видимо, первый селект оформляется с помощью плагина при событии загрузки документа, а второй никак, т.е. второй селект не присутствует на странице в момент срабатывания плагина.

Если вы используете фрэймворк `jQuery`, не очень понятно, зачем Вы пишете такие крокодилы как:

```
Document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText
```

Возможно, данную проблему можно решить используя `jQuery` и его обработчик событий [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), который срабатывает в случае с динамически появляющимися элементами, как раз как в вашем случае.

Если этот метод не подойдет, то, в случае успешного ответа сервера, динамический элемент необходимо собрать как `DOM` элемент, вызвать на нем действие плагина и прикрепить его к нужному элементу `span`. Для этого ответ сервера переделать в формат `json` (данные в массиве передать функции [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.json.php)), установить заголовок и распечатать полученный `json`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $jsonData;
```

Итого ваш `javascript` будет получать `json`, который можно распарсить и прочитать:

```
//вместо - document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)
//i.e. data = {'value1': 'verbose1'; 'value2': 'verbose2'; 'value3': 'verbose3'}
```

который далее используем для формирования `DOM` элемента `select` по след. принципу:

```
var selectEl = $('<select />');
$.each(data , function(key, value) {
    selectEl.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
});
selectEl.jqTransform(); //trigger plugin
selectEl.appendTo('#txt2'); //append to target element
```

Код не тестировался, воспринимайте как мое видение решения данной задачи с практическими вставками кода.

Comment: Действительно,этот код можно было еще проще реализовать($.ajax.. и.т.д ),просто сроки поджимают,и времени переписать,а заодно и подучить ajax+jquery совершенно нет.
По поводу вашего варианта,спасибо за хороший и развернутый ответ,я учту и попробую применить.

Comment: Вы слишком усложнили то, что уже сделано. 

Зачем лишние телодвижения с json и собирание объекта на клиенте? 

Зачем ругать нативные методы js для вставки элемента и советовать использовать jquery обвертку(которая все-равно вызовет нативный innerHTML или appendChild) если кроме вставки больше ничего не требуется?

Comment: передача html как в виде ответа ajax это плохая практика, одно это заставляет использовать json. Привыкать работать правильно даже в небольших задачах это основа нормального кода в больших проектах. Приделать небольшой костылик конечно легко и быстро, после года работы на таких костыликах к коду притрагиваться не хочется